# mounting a shared folder I have on mac (HOST) machine using WSL in a virtualbox Windows (guest)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

My host machine is a Mac (and I have a folder on the Mac I want to share) with my Windows Virtual Box using WSL

Windows sees the folder no problem. If I type  `net use` at the command line I see the folder:

```
C:\Users\claudio>net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Y:        \\VBoxSvr\claudio         VirtualBox Shared Folders
The command completed successfully.
```

If I go to the WSL shell and type: `net.exe use` I can also see the folder.

```
C:\Users\claudio>net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Y:        \\VBoxSvr\claudio         VirtualBox Shared Folders
The command completed successfully.
```

However, from WSL I cannot browse to the folder location  as I would usually do on a Linux system: `cd /mnt/y` the only drive I see is c.

Doing:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/y
sudo mount -t drvfs '\\VboxSrv\claudio' /mnt/y
```

as someone suggested doesn't work.

I now see the drive y but not the specific folder (I suspect this is because the file system of the folder is a Mac one)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/) to create a virtual drive, and mirror the contents of your virtualbox shared folder drive to it.

There are some exmaples on the docs: https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/wiki/Use-Mirror-example

After that you will be able to mount the dokan virtual drive on wsl using drvfs, something like this:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d
$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```